# I need to build new matrices by selecting alternate columns of the original matrix

Tags: r, select, matrix, lapply, cbind

I have a matrix where the first column is the ID of the samples, the columns 2 to 15 are the observed presences of 14 fish species, and the columns 16 to 29 are the predicted presences of the same 14 species.

I need to build 14 matrices (1 per species) with 3 columns each: first column = ID of the samples (e.g. column 1 of the original matrix), 2nd column = observed presence of the species, 3rd column = predicted presence of the species.

Lets say that A is the ID of my samples:

`A<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

B are the observed values for my species

`B<-replicate(14,rnorm(10))`

C are the predicted values for my species

`C<-replicate(14,rnorm(10))`

So I have the matrix "data":

`data<-cbind(A, B, C)`

I want to do something like this

`A1<-cbind(data[,1],data[,2],data[,16])`
`A2<-cbind(data[,1],data[,3],data[,17])`

etc.. until having A1 to A14 matrices, one for each species. I suspect that I need to use the lapply function but I am lost. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to create a `list` of `matrices` by looping through the sequence of columns

```
lst <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(B)), function(i) cbind(A, B= B[,i], C=C[,i]))
names(lst) <- paste0("A", seq_along(lst))
```

It is better to keep it in a `list` instead of creating multiple objects in the global environment.  But, if we need it anyway

```
list2env(lst, .GlobalEnv)
```